# GCP Cloud Domain Transfer from One Project to Another Project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-domain-api

Hello Thank you for reading this post.

Firstly I created a project, for example, test01 and registered domain, test02.online, on Cloud Domain in test01. Then I deleted the project, test01, and created new project, test02 in the same day.

There is no test02.online on Cloud Domain in test01 anymore. It disappeared.

I confirmed the existence of test02.online in Google Domain and its DNS.

How can I transfer or display test02.online on Cloud Domain in test02?

I understand that the domain, test02.online, is independednt from any project and linked to the project through DNS such as DNS zone though, I want to manage test2.online on Cloud Domain in test02 for simplicity.

Thank you indeed in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Domains is not built around projects. The identity of the domain owner controls the domain.

Project-based Google Cloud Domains is currently under preview. There isn't yet a way to transfer a registered domain between projects. The domain can be exported to Google Domains. Note: A domain's DNS servers don't have to be in the same project as Google Cloud Domains; they can be found in any project. Make sure Google Domains is already managing your domain before exporting it by clicking this [link](https://domains.google.com/). The identity that is registered with the domain must be used by you. Go to the other project, set up the DNS servers, and then proceed if the domain shows up.

If a project is erased while the registration period is still active, you should be able to retrieve the domain by going to Google Domains, contacting Google Domains support, and confirming that your details match those in the WHOIS.

See this official [doc](https://cloud.google.com/domains/docs/deprecations/feature-deprecations) for more information

Refer to this [doc](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/9018323?hl=en) about  Restore a deleted or expired domain name